# NodeJS passing a ws object to a child process

Tags: node.js, tcp, process, websocket, subprocess

I'm trying to pass a ws object to a child process.

In the node documentation under child processes (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) under the "send" function it says the 2nd parameter can be a TCP object which the child & parent can share.

When I try to pass a ws object it says "throw new TypeError('This handle type can\'t be sent');". I guess it's because it's a ws object and not a tcp object, but I was wondering if there's anyway to achieve the same effect with ws object instead of a tcp object...? As ws is just a wrapper around the tcp object that conforms to the websocket standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, a WS socket is not a raw TCP object. TCP sockets are layer-4 constructs, and can be passed between processes as raw handles (basically, integers, in most underlying OS metaphors.) The operating system itself handles all of the TCP operations like session state management, and this is important when processes want to pass handles around.

WebSockets are totally different. They're a metaphorical construct on top of a layer-7 (HTTP) connection. In layers 5+, applications themselves do quite a bit of communication beyond what the operating system provides - dealing with headers, cookies, WS connection states, etc. This is more than can be encoded in an integer handle, so Node doesn't currently have a way to pass them around.

Typically, most apps that require connections to be passed around in this way accept the TCP connection at a raw level, pass THAT to the child, then allow the child to handle the HTTP (and WS) from there. They don't share this work between a master and child process. Sorry it's not the answer you want, but your application architecture will need rethinking if you've built around this expectation. It's not just Node that's like this, by the way. This would apply to any other language such as Python or Ruby as well, because all of these are just high-level wrappers around Berkeley Sockets constructs, and socket passing in that layer is handle-based, as described above.

Comment: I see. Does the same apply to the cluster class too? (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Can ws be used with that or does it need to be a raw http/tcp object?

Comment: Yes. The Cluster class is just syntactic sugar around child_process itself. It provides a number of useful components for starting and stopping child workers, maintaining a set worker count, and letting children and parents talk to one another. But it doesn't add anything extra to allow WS connections to be moved around.